# How can I hide Accordion Content in react-native-collapsible

Tags: react-native, react-native-collapsible

I am using react-native-collapsible in my application to achieve accordion view.

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible

It works fine but we got a change in requirement where we do not want the Accordion click functionality i.e the Accordion should not expand on click. I can do it by creating a separate div but I am thinking of a work around of reusing the same react-native-collapsible and achieve the same.

Code for Accordion-

```
    const SECTIONS = [
      {
        title: 'First',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum...',
      },
      {
        title: 'Second',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum...',
      },
    ];

class AccordionView extends Component {
  state = {
    activeSections: [],
  };


     _renderContent = section => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text>{section.content}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      };
}

  render() {
    return (
      <Accordion
        sections={SECTIONS}
        activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
        renderSectionTitle={this._renderSectionTitle}
        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
        renderContent={this._renderContent}
        onChange={this._updateSections}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

So, to achieve that, I am trying to remove renderContent function completely from my Accordion but this gives me error -

```
TypeError: renderContent is not a function
```

Can someone let me know if there is a way I can hide the the Accordion content while reusing the same codebase. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I cannot understand how "section.content" fills! How you pass it to the _renderContent? Is it a state?

Comment: Its in the link however I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... do you want to hide the accordion, and disable the expand on touch feature, then you don't want an accordion , just use the animate api of react native. However, that module has the disabled property to disable user interaction, and activeSections property to open a section from code like you are doing

```
<Accordion
        sections={SECTIONS}
        activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
        renderSectionTitle={this._renderSectionTitle}
        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
        renderContent={this._renderContent}
        onChange={this._updateSections}
        disabled={true} //add this 
        touchableComponent={TouchableWithoutFeedback} //here to disable animation
      />
```

Is that what you want? it would help if you posted an image or gif example.

**EDIT**

Yeah, to disable the touch feedback you can use touchablewithoutfeedback in the touchableComponent property (see code avobe). As an alternative you can use [this module fork](https://github.com/RZulfikri/react-native-collapse-view)  or react-native-collapse-view , wich also offers open and close programatically for individual elements (maybe use a flatlist for multiple). You can use the animate api / layoutanimation api , since you can create your own component and fit it to your needs , you can find more about them  [here](https://tutorialscapital.com/react-native-dynamically-expand-collapse-slidedown-slideup-view-using-layoutanimation-tutorial/) and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations), but the module has everything you need for now so i wouldn´t suggest it anymore.

Comment: I have just added disabled attribute as you suggested, this does disable the accordion expand however, I see the color on touch changes for a second.

Comment: Also I did not understand what you mean by "just use the animate api of react native". Do I need to remove this Accordion and implement it as a plain view?

Comment: This does not work. It gives error that 'TouchableWithoutFeedback is not defined'

Comment: Did you imported TouchableWithoutFeedback from react-native ? ;-;